# vite Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "vertx" from "node_modules\xxxxx". Does the file exist?

Tags: vite

[vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "vertx" from "node_modules\vue3-html2pdf\node_modules\html2pdf.js\dist\include\html2pdf.es.js?v=81457e47". Does the file exist?
Plugin: vite:import-analysis
File: E:/code/vue/curriculum/node_modules/vue3-html2pdf/node_modules/html2pdf.js/dist/include/html2pdf.es.js?v=81457e47:1:45
1  |  import * as __require_for_vite_KSDlOT from "vertx";
|                                              ^
2  |  import jsPDF from "jspdf";
3  |  import html2canvas from "html2canvas";
at formatError (file:///E:/code/vue/curriculum/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-ca21228b.js:41418:46)
at TransformContext.error (file:///E:/code/vue/curriculum/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-ca21228b.js:41414:19)
at normalizeUrl (file:///E:/code/vue/curriculum/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-ca21228b.js:39706:33)
at async TransformContext.transform (file:///E:/code/vue/curriculum/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-ca21228b.js:39840:47)
at async Object.transform (file:///E:/code/vue/curriculum/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-ca21228b.js:41685:30)
at async loadAndTransform (file:///E:/code/vue/curriculum/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-ca21228b.js:39479:29)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ryz6.png)

Comment: try `npm add vertx`

Comment: I get this error too. it's a tertiary dep, so adding vertx via `npm add vertx` to the project would do nothing to fix the error. Looks like a Vite bug to me. Here's the [repo and branch](https://github.com/dkilgore-eightfold/octupledownstream/tree/dkilgore-eightfold/storybook-vite-test-runner-upgrade) where I get the error (though it's yarn in my case). Gotta say though migrating a complex project from Webpack to Vite is definitely not zero config.